# How to call my function in another function

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an value from the user in `getInteger`.

I need to get the output from `sqInteger` in `getInteger`.

No matter how I set up the parameters or indent the `sqInteger` function, variable `x` is undefined.

I added a return line to try and pass the `x` variable, but that's definitely not helping.

Please help me understand what I'm missing!

```
def getInteger():
   while True:
      try:
          x = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
      except ValueError:
          print()
          print('That\'s not an integer.  Try again.')
          continue
      else:
          return x
          print(x)
          break

def sqInteger(getInteger, x):
   y = x**2
   print(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the entire code?  You need to call the `getInteger()` function at some point in the code before that loop will begin.  You're also not calling function `sqInteger()` at any point.

Your exception handler will immediately stop evaluating the `try` block and move down to the `except` block upon a non-integer being typed into the input.  Therefore, you can place a call to the `sqInteger()` function after the `input()` function.  If the user types a non-integer into the terminal, it will move down to your Exception handler and prompt the user to retry.  If they enter an integer, the code will continue to evaluate and run the function `sqInteger`.

For this, you also do not need to pass `getInteger` into the `sqInteger()` function.  You are technically allowed to pass functions as parameters in Python but it's not necessary for this and probably out of the scope of this program.

So the following code would be suitable:

```
def getInteger():
   while True:
      try:
          x = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
          # variable 'squared' now receives the return value from the function
          squared = sqInteger(x) # call to function sqInteger necessary for this function to be executed
      except ValueError:
          print('That\'s not an integer.  Try again.')
          continue
      else:
          print(x) # if user entered 2, prints 2, not 4
          return x # this value is still only what the user input, not the result of sqInteger()
          break

def sqInteger(x):
   y = x**2
   print(y)
   return y #you need to return values from functions in order to access it from outside the function
```

The reason you pass a variable into a function (as a parameter) is to give that function access to that variable.  Creating a function creates a local scope for that function so that variables named within that function are in a separate namespace from variables outside that function.  This is useful in large programs where many variables might exist and you need to keep them separate.

Because you've separately defined a sqrt function, it does not have access to variables outside of its scope.  You need to pass in variables that you'd like it to have access to.

You also need to call functions before they will run.  Defining a function only serves to set up the function so that it can be called as one functional unit.  It's useful for separating concerns within a program.  The ability to call a function is useful because it allows you to separate your code out and only mention a single call to a function rather than having the entire functionality jumbled in with the rest of the code.  It also allows for reusability of code.

You can also have access to the result of the squared integer by returning a value and assigning this value to a function call, like such:

```
# lets say x = 4
squared = sqInteger(x)

def sqInteger(x):
   y = x**2
   return y
```

This would NOT work:

```
x = input("Enter integer") #lets say you enter 3
squared = sqInteger() 
print(squared)

def sqInteger(): 
    print(x) # error: x is not defined
    return x**2 # error: x is not defined
```

The function does not have access to outside variables like `x`.  It must be passed these variables as parameters so that you can call this function and set the parameters at will.  This is for the sake of modularity in a program.  You can pass it all sorts of different integers as parameters and it allows you to have a resuable function for anytime you need to square an integer.

Edit:  Sorry this was a mess, I finally fixed all the errors in my explanation though...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's extremely helpful!  When I implement your edits into my code, it does not print the integer entered by the user-this is a requirement in addition to the printing the squared integer. Is it skipping this print command because sqInteger(x) is called directly after input?

Comment: You want to print the input by the user and not the squared value, correct?  You would actually need to go to the `else` block and move the `print(x)` statement up above the 'return' statement.  A return statement will stop execution of the current function and immediately go back to the place where the function was called--ergo, the print(x) function after that will not be run.  I'll edit the main code block above to reflect this, as well.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you so much!